# Does VS 2008 MSDN Professional subscription include previous editions of Visual Studio (e.g. 2005, 2003, Interdev)?

Tags: msdn

Couple of customers are still using Visual Interdev and VS.net 2003. 
Now the only way i know to get those editors is by having a msdn premium subscription. 
Wanted to check can a MSDN professional subscription also get me older VS softwares?
-Paritosh

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what is included in a web service subscription rather than about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MSDN Subscriber Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx) and [MSDN Subscriptions Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/index/default.aspx) pages.

Answer (score 0):

VS2005: Yes

VS2003: No

InterDev: No

Comment: Is it "n-1" principle?
Not able to find this info on msdn site.